# pagination in struts

Tags: java, struts2

I have a requirement where I have to fetch some records from the database and then I have to show 50 records per page on a JSP. The page will be having First, Previous, Next and Last buttons on the screen. Has anyone implemented similar functionality in struts or similar framework? also i dont want to get all records at once. please guide me how to implement?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use the [Displaytag](http://displaytag.sourceforge.net/1.2/) library for this. It works great in combination with Struts and jsp and provides sorting and pagination.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can try some JQuery plugin that handles all client-side processing and take data from the server-side code. You migh try http://www.datatables.net/ because it handles pagination, filtering, ordering and has much more features. Here is explained how you can integrate DataTables with java servlet application http://www.codeproject.com/KB/java/JQuery-DataTables-Java.aspx.

Answer (score 0):

1)in Action Class Calculate total number of pages in action(fetch it from  it from database and calculate like totalPages=totalEntries/pageSize)

2) send pageNumber from jsp(while user click on page no), send pageSize from jsp(if user has to specify pageSize) or from action to Business.
String query = "select empid, ename from employee by joindate desc limit " + start + "," + pageSize;

Calculate Start like
int start = (pageNumber * pageSize - pageSize);

Answer (score 0):

Use Strust2 criteria API to set max results

```
List<Class_Name> records = new ArrayList<Class_Name>();
private static SessionFactory sf = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
Session s = sf.openSession();
Criteria cr = s.createCriteria(Class_Name.class);
cr.setMaxResults(50);


records = cr.list();
s.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [Struts 2 Jq Grid plugin](http://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/source/browse/trunk/struts2-jquery-grid-showcase/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/content/grid-subgrid.jsp?r=1751) It is plugin designed for struts2 .. `display tag` is depreciated. 
You can achieve by just the use `struts2 jqgrid tags` and there are lot of other features also there